# What is the " base step" in this proof by induction regarding an elementary fact of FOL's syntax? ( "Classical logic" in SEP)

Tags: soft-question, induction, first-order-logic

Source : https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-classical/#BuilBloc

---

Here is the proof ( where the " rules (2)-(7) ) " refered to are the formation rules of  formulas) :

Let us temporarily use the term “unary marker” for the negation symbol (¬) or a quantifier followed by a variable (e.g., ∀x,∃z).

**Lemma 2**. Each formula consists of a string of zero or more unary markers followed by either an atomic formula or a formula produced using a binary connective, via one of clauses (3)–(5).

> Proof: We proceed by induction on the complexity of the formula or, in
> other words, on the number of formation rules that are applied.

> The Lemma clearly holds for atomic formulas.

> Let n be a natural number, and suppose that the Lemma holds for any formula constructed >from n or fewer instances of clauses (2)–(7). Let θ be a formula constructed
> from n+1 instances. The Lemma holds if the last clause used to
> construct θ was either (3), (4), or (5). If the last clause used to
> construct θ was (2), then θ is ¬ψ. Since ψ was constructed with n
> instances of the rule, the Lemma holds for ψ (by the induction
> hypothesis), and so it holds for θ. Similar reasoning shows the Lemma
> to hold for θ if the last clause was (6) or (7). By clause (8), this
> exhausts the cases, and so the Lemma holds for θ, by induction.

My question is : does the base case consist in  the assertion that the property holds for atomic formulas?

I can see that the induction hypothesis is that the property holds when n instances of rules (2)-(7) are applied.

I see that after that, the induction step is proved : if the property holds for $n$ applications, it also holds for $n+1$ applications.

***But I cannot detect the base step*** Does it consist in the assertion that the property is true of atomic formulas?

If it is the case , what relation has the base step to do with number $n$?

Does the atomic formulas case represent $n=0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the base case is the case for atomic formulas, and this corresponds to "$n=0$:" when $n=0$ we're limited to formulas constructed without using clauses $(2)$ through $(7)$ at all, that is, only those formulas constructed via clause $(1)$. And all clause $(1)$ does is give us the atomic formulas:

> 1. All atomic formulas of $\mathcal{L}1K=$ are formulas of $\mathcal{L}1K=$.

Comment: Thanks for answering this basic question!